# Allow to download file from my REST endpoint in Golang using 3rd party API

Tags: rest, api, go, download, zip

This might sound odd but I am developing an endpoint(REST) that allows users to  download the file(may be a zip). 
So I am hitting an 3rd party API to get the file and then I have to pass that to  end users.

I can't expose 3rd party APIs. 
I am quite new to Golang and REST APIs as well. I can explore the concept but anyone has any idea, what is the best way to allow download of file from your REST endpoint which is actually coming from 3rd party.

I know this is very bad way to ask question but I have no idea what should I  explore or read any blog which gives me this idea.

I am not looking for code, but more of an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang has the abstraction of `io.Reader` which encapsulates almost anything that can be read in binary format.
Usually if you have a file coming from a 3rd party API, you would have at least one way to build an `io.Reader` from that file, whether it's an HTTP request, gRPC, or local file.

If you have your `io.Reader`, then definitely the requesting party would provide an `io.Writer` to allow you to write the response they are requesting. After this point all you have to do is bridge the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` to copy on the fly the file from the 3rd party API to the requesting party using `io.Copy` or `io.CopyN` for example.

Comment: Please , can you provide an example .

Answer (score 2):

Adding code snippet to what @Seaskyways has explained above.

```
return middleware.ResponderFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r runtime.Producer) {
        fn := filepath.Base(filePath)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%q", fn))
        io.Copy(w, file)
        defer os.Remove(filePath)
        file.Close()
    })
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply with help of gin.Context.FileAttachment(path,filename)

[go to this respo.](https://github.com/02amanag/upload-and-download-file)